# How can one use ezplot in MATLAB to effectively draw implicit curves and surfaces?

Tags: matlab, plot, implicit, curve

I need to draw a 2D ellipse using its general form `(x-c)'A(x-c)=1`

I would like to know how to do this effectively in MATLAB using [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html).

Answer (score 5):

This answer is applicable to almost any problem which can be formulated as an implicit surface/curve in MATLAB. I am going to demonstrate it on an ellipse.

**Short Version:**

```
A = [5 4; 4 5]    
c = [1; 2]    
elFunc = @(A11,A22,A12,A21,c1,c2,x,y) (c1-x).*(A11*(c1-x)+A21*(c2-y))+(c2-y).*(A12*(c1-x)+A22*(c2-y))-1    
ezplot(@(x,y) elFunc(A(1,1),A(2,2),A(1,2),A(2,1),c(1),c(2),x,y), [0 2 0 4])
```

**Long Version:**

An ellipse can be written implicitly in its most general form (for any dimension) as

```
(x-c)'A(x-c) = 1 or (x-c)'A(x-c)-1 = 0
```

where x,c are in R^n and A is an nxn matrix.

In order to get this into a form that MATLAB can use we can use the symbolic toolbox.
For a 2D ellipse we write:

```
syms A11 A12 A21 A22 c1 c2 x y real
impl = ([x y]-[c1 c2])*[A11 A12; A21 A22]*([x;y]-[c1;c2])-1
```

This produces the following output:

```
(c1 - x)*(A11*(c1 - x) + A21*(c2 - y)) + (c2 - y)*(A12*(c1 - x) + A22*(c2 - y)) - 1
```

We dont need the symbolic toolbox anymore so we just copy the string, vectorize it by adding the dot operator version and turn it into a function

```
elFunc = @(A11,A22,A12,A21,c1,c2,x,y) (c1-x).*(A11*(c1-x)+A21*(c2-y))+(c2-y).*(A12*(c1-x)+A22*(c2-y))-1
```

Now we can use ezplot to draw our curve. ezplot assumes that when you give it a function handle it needs to solve for func = 0 so our curve is already described by elFunc in implicit format.
All that is left for us to do is to define the domain over which we want ezplot to try and draw the curve. The following example demonstrates the result:

```
A = [5 4; 4 5]    
    c = [1; 2]    
    elFunc = @(A11,A22,A12,A21,c1,c2,x,y) (c1-x).*(A11*(c1-x)+A21*(c2-y))+(c2-y).*(A12*(c1-x)+A22*(c2-y))-1    
    ezplot(@(x,y) elFunc(A(1,1),A(2,2),A(1,2),A(2,1),c(1),c(2),x,y), [0 2 0 4])
```

[image: Ellipse plotted by ezplot in MATLAB]

Answer (score 4):

This answer is exactly the same as @twerdster's answer, except the notation is a bit more Matlabby:

```
A = [5 4; 4 5];
c = [1 2];

elFunc = @(x,y) sum(([x(:)-c(1) y(:)-c(2)] * A) .* [x(:)-c(1) y(:)-c(2)], 2) - 1;
ezplot(elFunc, [0 2 0 4])
```

As a final remark: as both our answers already kind of indicate, `ezplot` is intended for things that are **easy-to-plot**. The ellipse is already on the edge of still being 'easy' enough for anonymous functions and `ezplot`.

In general, I'd suggest you avoid using `ezplot` for anything harder than `ezplot(@(x)sin(x).*cos(2*x))` or so. It is much more fruitful to practice and become fluent in `function`s and `plot()`, `surf()`, and friends.

Comment: It is indeed more Matlabby :)

Comment: +1 for indicating that `ezplot` should not be used for "complex" (i.e. real-life) plotting purposes.